# CSVREADER in creating a fancy table

Tags: tables, pdftex, multirow, csv

I'm really struggling to create the following table in LaTeX where only the data comes from a csv file (the numbers in the file is in exactly the same format as it is in this table). The challenge is to have merged cells on the left. My LaTeX document starts with:
\documentclass[11pt,times,letter]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

[image]

Here is the code that I currently have for the table, but it has all numbers hardcoded.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Annualized Sharpe ratios and standard deviations (in brackets) of four monthly rebalanced portfolios spanning the period January 6, 2006 through October 19, 2018. We condition on the event that the market index has monthly returns smaller than $-6.7\%$ ($R_m<-6.7\%$). The maximum values of the Sharpe ratios are highlighted in bold.} \label{TableSharpeRatiosMonthly2}
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{US stocks}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   & $q_m=0.5$ & $q_m=0.3$ \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$q_p=0.2$} & $CoER^{\leq}$ & $\mathbf{-1.5538} \ (0.2766)$  & $\mathbf{0.0659} \ (0.3538)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $CoER^{=}$ & $-4.0990 \ (0.2104)$ & $-3.2071 \ (0.2255)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& Min.Var. & $-2.7377 \ (0.2406)$ & $-2.7377 \ (0.2406)$\\ \cline{2-4}
& $1/n$ & $-6.1798 \ (0.2255)$ & $-6.1798 \ (0.2255)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$q_p=0.1$} & $CoER^{\leq}$ & $\mathbf{-1.9243} \ (0.2638)$  & $\mathbf{-1.0906} \ (0.2946)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $CoER^{=}$ & $-4.1003 \ (0.2104)$ & $-3.3969 \ (0.2219)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& Min.Var. & $-2.7377 \ (0.2406)$ & $-2.7377 \ (0.2406)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $1/n$ & $-6.1798 \ (0.2255)$ & $-6.1798 \ (0.2255)$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\vspace*{10pt}
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Canadian stocks}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}   & $q_m=0.5$ & $q_m=0.3$ \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$q_p=0.2$} & $CoER^{\leq}$ & $-3.8621 \ (0.2801)$  & $-3.8650 \ (0.2890)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $CoER^{=}$ & $-3.8872 \ (0.2465)$ & $-3.8912 \ (0.2604)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& Min.Var. & $\mathbf{-3.8466} \ (0.2692)$ & $\mathbf{-3.8466} \ (0.2692)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $1/n$ & $-7.0936 \ (0.1028)$ & $-7.0936 \ (0.1028)$ \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{$q_p=0.1$} & $CoER^{\leq}$ & $-3.8596 \ (0.2759)$  & $-3.8630 \ (0.2819)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $CoER^{=}$ & $-3.8862 \ (0.2465)$ & $-3.8895 \ (0.2576)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& Min.Var. & $\mathbf{-3.8466} \ (0.2692)$ &  $\mathbf{-3.8466} \ (0.2692)$ \\ \cline{2-4}
& $1/n$ & $-7.0936 \ (0.1028)$ & $-7.0936 \ (0.1028)$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show your csv file and have you a tex code you tried you can show us?

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick reply! I added the code but I don't see how I can attach a file. The csv file is literally the last two columns in the table.